# Why did someone pull the device tag from this question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7160/why-cant-i-boot-into-recovery-mode) about booting into recovery mode [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7160/why-cant-i-boot-into-recovery-mode) and tagged it with "t-mobile G1" because that's the device that was giving me grief and because I suspected that the phone manufacturer and model might be relevant to the answer. Looking at the answers, it does seem to be relevant: "Apparently download and recovery modes are merged for the G1."

Al Everett went through the other night and pulled the "t-mobile g1" tag off of most of my posts. In most cases I understand -- ultimately the questions and answers weren't G1 specific (though I didn't know that when I asked them). In this case the answer was so I'm curious about the logic behind pulling the tag. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, guys. I definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I do think the tag should have stayed.  But Al is right that we have way too many questions tagged with the device for no real reason.  If you're not sure if it's relevant, just mention your device in the question and leave off the tags.  See also: [Should we discourage phone model tags in non-phone-specific questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-we-discourage-phone-model-tags-in-non-phone-specific-questions/)

Answer (score 2):

Al is correct, the device specific tags are getting a little out of hand but I'm going to have to agree with Amanda and Matthew Read on this one.  I think that it is sufficiently device specific to warrant a device specific tag.  I think it's important to consider that tags are not necessarily mutually exclusive.  I restored the tag but shouldn't it be tagged "htc-g1" instead of "tmobile-g1"?  I thought the practice was "manufacturer-model" not "carrier-model".

Comment: Which is fine. I'm only human after all. And, yes, the convention on model tags is "manufacturer-model". Carrier, if it's relevant, should be a separate tag.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I'm not sure how I came up with the "tmobile-g1" tag but it was already in use. Presumably because for a lot of folks the manufacturer was obfuscated. I'm off to read up on clearing up tags so I can make some recommendations about getting the "t-mobile-g1" out of the tag prompts altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Because it didn't seem device-specific.

We have far too many questions here tagged with the user's device, but neither the question nor answers are specific to that device.

Comment: Thx for the edits, sorry about putting your name all over the original.

Comment: No worries. It's a legitimate question.