# Should tags reguarding the model of the phone be added?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we discourage phone model tags in non-phone-specific questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-we-discourage-phone-model-tags-in-non-phone-specific-questions)

For example if the question is regarding something on the Sony Ericson Xperia phone, should the tag be added to the question? One may answer "only if it's relevant" but it's not always apparent if it's relevant or not (e.g. an app not working).

Comment: This has been discussed quite a bit; I believe our working policy is to add the tag only when you know it's relevant or have good reason to believe it is.  If it's just the case of an app not working and you know nothing about its behavior on other OS versions or devices, then the OS version and particular device are good to include in the question but not in the tags.

Comment: Tags should be used to describe the question. They should **not** be used to provide information about the asker's device. Most of the time the issue has little to nothing to do with the device the asker actually has.